# Template isn't being rendered

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I am developing a WordPress website using a minimalist JavaScript framework + Timber.  I have noticed that between pages, there is about 1500ms delay. I wanted to use W3 Total Cache, or WP Super Cache to see if I can use the cache features so it can load the pages faster.

It does seem to be faster, however I have some rendering problems.  Because i'm using Timber, I have partial templates, one example looks like this.

*Contacts.twig*

```
{% extends "_base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if not isAJAX %}<section>{% endif %}        
        <div>
            <div>
                <section> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus quis doloribus libero et harum, molestiae, nam alias voluptatem sequi rem inventore aliquid reiciendis</p>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% if not isAJAX %}</section>{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I activate W3 Total Cache, when I reload this page, http://example.com/contact, it only renders out this particular HTML strings, there is no header or footer, meaning it does not render out the `_base.twig`.

In my `contact.php`, it looks like

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Contact Template
 */

$context = Timber::get_context();

Timber::render('views/contact/contact.twig', $context);
```

Are there any Timber/WordPress experts who know how I can use W3 Total Cache correctly?

Comment: It work if you disable W3 total Cache or other cache plugins?

Comment: Yes of course, works normally without any cache plugin enabled.

Comment: take a look this, maybe it interest you https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/Performance#cache-everything

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. I use Fast Velocity Minify along with W3 and it fixed my load speed issue.  Below are some links that may work too.  I finally reached a score of 90 for mobile and desktop after tweaking for a while.  Let me Know if this works.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-fix-render-blocking-java-script-in-wordpress/

Speed Booster Pack Plug In
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-use-along-with-w3-cache/

Answer (score 0):

**W3 Total Cache** will skip the Twig/Timber layer of your files and serve static pages via whatever mechanism the plugin or settings dictate.

**Cache the Entire Twig File and Data**

When rendering, use the $expires argument in Timber::render. For example:

```
$data['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();
Timber::render('index.twig', $data, 600);
```

Timber will cache the template for 10 minutes (600 / 60 = 10). But here's the cool part. Timber hashes the fields in the view context. This means that as soon as the data changes, the cache is automatically invalidated (yay!).

Full Parameters:

```
Timber::render(
    $filenames,
    $data,
    $expires, /** Default: false. False disables cache altogether. When passed an array, the first value is used for non-logged in visitors, the second for users **/
    $cache_mode /** Any of the cache mode constants defined in TimberLoader **/
);
```

For more information [click here](https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/Performance#cache-everything)

Comment: @anon you check my answer